# How to validate referrer url using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to reload my page whenever the referrer URL is equal to a link but I would love to use like operator, I don't want to use equal to since the level id will not always be the same. Please help me with the correct code.

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (document.referrer = https://www.maocular.org/membership-account/membership-confirmation/?level=10)  { 
       location.reload(forceGet);
    }
    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: You can always do a substring check. If the first 68 characters are equal to `https://www.maocular.org/membership-account/membership-confirmation/`, then it's fine to reload.

Answer (score 1):

you can use match function of String(javascript) which takes String or Regex as input so as the name suggests match does a check with the string passed to it,if a match is found then match function returns an Array, if a match is not found then match returns null. 
Solution for your code:

```
if(document.referer.match('https://www.maocular.org/membership-account/membership-confirmation/?level=')) {
   location.reload(forceGet);
  }
```

Explanation: 
so as document.referrer returns a string we can make use of match function of String Class which exists in Javascript, and inside match we have passed a direct string instead of regex as there's only match required, in case you need more than one match use regex (|) and so on.

Refer this doc for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: It is telling me error. Guess you didn't close the opening of ( Pls help me check

Comment: yes sorry for that, I have edited it for you :) Thanks for pointing it

Comment: The Code is not working but have been able to use the Format you gave me to write this out and it works, only that i find it difficult to put it inside PHP code can you help me with that

`<script language='javascript'>
            var referrer = document.referrer;
            var Rurl = 'https://maocular.org/membership-account/membership-confirmation/?level';
            if referrer.match(Rurl));
            {location.reload();} 
</script>`

Comment: <script language='javascript'> var referrer = document.referrer; var Rurl = 'https://maocular.org/membership-account/membership-confirmation/?level'; if(referrer.match(Rurl)) {location.reload();} </script>

Please correct your if like this, if cannot have semi colon, a semi colon indicates that if function is done with the job, you may even try one line if, 

refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
   if (document.referrer == https://www.maocular.org/membershipaccount/membership-confirmation/?level=10) 
   { 
        location.reload(forceGet);
     }
    </script>';
?>
```

In your condition, change to **==** from **=**

Comment: This doesn't fix OP's problem. The problem is that he doesn't want to check on whatever is stated behind the `level` query. Or in this case even the entire query.